# What are ApplicationController/Helper/view responsible for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems they are not directly related to any particular app. So what should they be responsible in general? For example, what part of the app MVC should be placed at an application level instead of in any particular one. And how do we decide if we should put a particular piece of code in the helper or view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ApplicationController

The `ApplicationController` should usually be treated as a base class that inherits `ActionController::Base`. While technically you could point routed actions to the `ApplicationController`, it's bad form. It should be treated as the entry point between your application and Rails' code.

It provides a common layer of customisation where you can create methods that can be used in subclasses. These utility methods should usually be restricted to things that directly rely on the context of the HTTP request (such as session data). A good example is the `current_user` method that Clearance adds to your ApplicationController through a module.

Subclass the `ApplicationController` to add your RESTful controllers that can use those methods.

I've also found it to be a useful place to `rescue_from` errors and handle them gracefully rather than redirecting straight to a 500 error page.

#### views/application

I've usually found this to be a good place to put shared partials, like navigation and flash markup.

#### Helpers

I find I rarely use helpers at all, preferring presenters in their place. But if you have common logic through the app that needs a view context, the application's helper is the place to store it. Helpers used in shared partials in views/application usually fit here fairly well.